# How to check which implementation is used on a List of an Interface

Tags: java, interface, jgrapht

pretty new to Java, 
 I have a Graph of JGraphT with Employees as nodes and an Interface called "FeatureEdge" as edges.

I create some edges by reading through a database to connect my employees.

Now I want to export my edges by edge-type ( Location- or Interestedge ) but I have no clue how to know which of my `List<FeatureEdge> list` edges is of which implemented type.

Any suggestions, how I can get a type ? In C++ I would dynamic_cast every edge of my list to both types and check which one would work, but I don't know how to do it in Java,

Graph:

```java
public MultiGraph<Employee, FeatureEdge> graph = new Multigraph<>(FeatureEdge.class);
```

Interface:

```
public interface FeatureEdge {}
```

Implementations:

```
public class LocationEdge implements FeatureEdge {
    private String location;

    public LocationEdge(String location){
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocation(){
        return this.location;
    }
}
```

```
public class InterestEdge implements FeatureEdge {
    private int interestStrength;

    public InterestEdge(int strength) {
        this.interestStrength = strength;
    }

    public int getInterestStrength() {
        return this.interestStrength;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `getClass()` method:

```
List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (List<?> list : Arrays.asList(linkedList, arrayList)) {
  System.out.println(list.getClass());
}
```

will print

```
class java.util.LinkedList
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, but I see that it was downvoted, can someone explain why this could be a bad approach?

Comment: @sav it doesn't answer your question. It does answer the title, but based on your question it doesn't seem you're interested in knowing which `List` implementation is used (and you shouldn't care about that anyway), but separating the contents of a list based on their type. So either this answer is wrong, or your question text is completely irrelevant to what you want.

Comment: I think Yuriy just used Lists as an example for an interface with 2 different implementations. That resembles my question :)

Comment: @sav I'd be interested in seeing how your implementation ends up with `getClass()`.

Comment: @Kayaman `for(FeatureEdge fe : list) {
   if(fe.getClass().equals(LocationEdge.class)){
      // do something
}
} `

Comment: Dear @Kayaman, what's up? The question was _How to check which implementation is used on a List of an Interface_ and I've answered. Didn't I? It's completely matches the question and the TS has confirmed that. It looks like exactly you didn't get the right mention. The code l've wrote is just a simplification to allow to the TS understand how it works.  If you think the `getClass()` won't work, give an explanation why so!